# Can't understand how params are set in list variable in my bash script

Tags: bash, parameters

I'm looking at a bash script with this:

```
PARAMS="%1;$1;$2;$3;$4;$5;$6;$7;$8;$9"
```

As I understand it, the parameters that are passed in on script execution will be added to this list.

When I run this:

```
runscript.sh CONFIG 2>&1
```

I see this error:

```
line 76: [[%1;CONFIG;;;;;;;;: command not found
```

where line 76 contains this:

```
if [[$PARAMS =~ "CONFIG" ]];
```

What does the `%1` mean and how should I run the script to get it to work?

Comment: You need a space after `[[`: `if [[ $PARAMS =~ "CONFIG" ]];`

Comment: BTW, `%1` was introduced by you... you should know its meaning, not us!

Comment: This is a common error: `[[` is actually a *command*, not mere syntax. You need whitespace to separate the command from the arguments. The error message is bash complaining that it can't find the command named `"[[$PARAMS"`

Comment: Sorry, I made a false claim. I was asked to get the script working. The author isn't available and my bash knowledge is very limited.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) can find this bug, and many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have a space after the `[[`. Once added the script worked.